# find the 2002th term of a binary sequence

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, combinatorics-on-words

> Source: 2002 UofT Math Competition, problem 9.

> A sequence whose entries are 0 and 1 has the property that, if each 0 is replaced by 01 and each 1 by 001, the sequence remains unchanged. What is the 2002th term of the sequence?

Let $S_1 = 0$ and for $k\ge 2$ let $S_k$ be obtained from $S_{k-1}$ by replacing every 0 in $S_{k-1}$ with $01$ and every $1$ with $001$. The crucial claim is that $S_k = S_{k-1}S_{k-2}S_{k-1}$ for all $k\ge 3$.

> I'm not sure if this can be shown using some form of induction.

The claim clearly justifies that the given sequence is well-defined, since $S_{k-1}$ is a prefix of $S_k$.

From the claim, the answer is easy: The length of the $S_k$'s for $1\leq k\leq 10$ are $1,2,5,12,29,70,169,408,985,2378.$ Let $S_{k,i}$ denote the ith symbol of $S_k$ where $i$ is at most the length of $S_k$. Then $S_{10,2002} = S_{9, 2002-985-408} = S_{9,609} = S_{8,609-408-169} = S_{8,32} = S_{7,32}=S_{6,32} = S_{4,32-29} = S_{3,3} = 0.$

Comment: Presumably $S_0$ should be the empty string. Is the question (you haven't framed one) how to prove the crucial claim? Induction seems like a great way; have you tried and gotten stuck somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Greg Martin indicated, you can use induction to prove the crucial claim. When I have encountered this kind of claim and its proof for the first time, I was like, uh, so easy and obvious?!

---

Let $\phi$ map strings to strings by replacing each $0$ with $01$ and each $1$ by $001$.

It is straightforward to see that **$\phi$ preserves string concatenation**, i.e., $\phi(st)=\phi(s)\phi(t)$, where $s$ and $t$ are two arbitrary strings, $st$ is the concatenation of $s$ and $t$.

You have constructed $S_k$ by $S_{k+1}=\phi(S_k)$.

Suppose $S_k = S_{k-1}S_{k-2}S_{k-1}$. Then
$$S_{k+1} = \phi(S_{k-1}S_{k-2}S_{k-1})=\phi(S_{k-1})\phi(S_{k-2})\phi(S_{k-1})=S_{k}S_{k-1}S_{k}$$

The base case is $S_3=01001=(01)0(01)=S_2S_1S_2$.

Comment: Honestly I'm a lot smarter than this; when I asked the question I wasn't even thinking about how to prove it.

Comment: The same happened to me on a problem like this about string morphism. I knew induction, but did not dare to even try.